# Getting 500 internal server error while calling Ajax JQuery service via Web service web method in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

> i want to call the Ajax to bind my listbox drpbuilding currently i am
>   doing by this but not able to call ajax.need help. the main objective
>   of using the Web service as i was not able to access the server
>   control(listbox) in static method here my page name is
>   TSRSearchlist.aspx and i want to bind the Listbox drpbuilding by ajax
>   !! here  BindBuildingList() is one of the function present in
>   TSP_TSR_SearchList class.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "TSR_SearchList.aspx/BindBuildingList",
                        data: '{}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (r) {
                            //debugger;
                            var k = r.d;
                            var ddlbuilding = $("#CP_Main_drpBuilding");
                            ddlbuilding.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                            if (r.d.length > 0) {
                                debugger;
                                for (var k = 0; k < r.d.length; k++) {
                                    ddlbuilding.append($("<option></option>").val(r.d[k].BuildingID).html(r.d[k].Building));
                                    ////  ddlbuilding.append("<option value=" + r[k].BuildingID + ">" +r[k].Building + "</option>");
                                    // $("#CP_Main_drpBuilding").append(ddlbuilding);
                                }

                                debugger;
                                $('#<%= drpbuilding.ClientID%>').next().find("button.multiselect").prop("disabled", false);
                            //$("#CP_Main_drpBuilding").attr("disabled", false);
                            //  $("#CP_Main_drpBuilding").css("display", "block");
                        }
                        else {
                            //  $("#CP_Main_drpBuilding").css("display", "None");
                        }
                    }
 },
                error: function (r) {
                    debugger;
                }
                    });
                });
```

**Backend code**

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services;
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
partial class TSP_TSR_SearchList
{
    [WebMethod()]
    Public Function BindBuildingList() List<PulseResponse.BLL.Building> BindBuildingList()
    {
        List<PulseResponse.BLL.Building> lstBuildings = default(List<PulseResponse.BLL.Building>);
        // Dim tsp As New TSP_TSR_SearchList

        lstBuildings = this.mBuildingBLL.Get_ContactSiteBuildingsList(p_ContactID: UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser().ContactID, p_ShowInactive: false);
        //A8075 - Amendment on Search Building Service Request in PulseTech



        if (lstBuildings.Count > 0) {
            this.drpBuilding.Enabled = true;
            this.drpBuilding.DataSource = lstBuildings;

        } else {
            this.drpBuilding.Enabled = false;
        }
        return lstBuildings;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll have to expand on "not able to call ajax". Do you get errors in your console/network tab? Errors on the server side? Just saying it doesn't work isn't really enough info for people to help you. You need to explain what debugging you did and what the exact problem is that you're having.

Comment: BTW as far as I can see `Public Function BindBuildingList() List<PulseResponse.BLL.Building> BindBuildingList()
    {` is not valid C#. Have you got a compile error, or is this just a typo?

Comment: yeah i got it it should have been called in .asmx rather than .aspx